# How to make accordion partially expand on hover and then fully open on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, accordion

Is it possible to make accordion partially expand and then fully open on click?

I have been using the following accordion but I am struggling to get this to work. http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

I would like to be able to control the height the accordion opens on hover and then for it to open fully on click.

Thank you in advanced for any help provided.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I have no idea where to start to achieve this. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: First create a simple accordion. Then try to work out for the hover functionality and then post your code here. This is your first time, so I have created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/du8obLps/) for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the accordion first and then add the hover functionality. below code maybe helpful:

```
$('.ui-accordion-header').on('mouseenter',function(){

if(!($(this).next('.ui-accordion-content').css('display')=="block"))
{
    $(this).next('.ui-accordion-content').addClass('hover');
}
});

$('.ui-accordion-header').on('mouseleave',function(){
    $(this).next('.ui-accordion-content').removeClass('hover');
});
```

The .hover class may look something like this:

```
.hover{display:block !important; height:50px !important;}
```